# BS3 - img-responsive class - why no max height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

bootstrap 3 includes the `.img-responsive` class
which applies these css settings

```
display: block;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
```

why is there no `max-height:100%;`?

I found adding this makes the pictures fit in terms of height as-well, but I'm not sure why it's being left out and not sure what the consequences are across other browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this: http://bootply.com/86201.
`max-height:100%` only fills the height of the viewport. While height:auto fills the available space (also below the viewport when scrolling down).
So height:auto seems more consistent with the grid based on width and a vertical scrollbar.
On a screen with small width and height images can became small with max-height:100% and not useful.

Note in the case you give the parent a fixed height and using max-width: 100%; and max-height:100%; for your images will help to resize the image and keep the aspect ratio:
http://bootply.com/86203 which is possible the answer you are looking for.

Comment: gotcha. in my case I'm limiting the max space in terms of height and width, and don't want the image to come out of it, but in the responsive grid system having the image scale accordingly makes sense.