# Why does Twitter Bootstrap 3.1.0 wastes horizontal space on wide screens?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Twitter Bootstrap 3.1.0 comes with rules that waste horizontal space on wide screens. When I remove them nothing seems to break, but something is probably breaking. Do you know if anything will break or why these were included? Thank you!

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Why does Bootstrap 3 force the container width to certain sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393264/why-does-bootstrap-3-force-the-container-width-to-certain-sizes),

> The official answer from the Bootstrap folks:
>
> > What it boils down to is that designing for specific breakpoints is easier (in my mind) than designing for unlimited, unknown sizes. The alternative you mention isn't wrong or bad, just different. I'd rather us maintain the tiers with very specific ranges

Bootstrap's grid system makes this a more feasible method. There shouldn't be anything breaking but if you find other spacing issues as you continue digging, this might be the reason.