# Is there a relationship between $container-max-width and $grid-breakpoint in Bootstrap v4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, grid, twitter-bootstrap-4

**Question:**
Is there a relationship between the default values assigned to the keys in the `$container-max-width` and `$grid-breakpoint` sass maps in [Bootstrap v4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com)?

**Context:**
I'm using [Bootstrap v4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) for a project and I'm looking at making some minor adjustments to the grid that it uses. It's trivial to set new values to the [variables](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#customizing-the-grid) which control how all of that works, but when I look at the [default values](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#variables) to try and get an idea of what I should be setting those new variables to, it appears that the `xl` values in the `$grid-breakpoints` & `$container-max-widths` maps are related via the `$grid-gutter-width-base` value like so:

```
(2 * $grid-gutter-width-base) + map-get($container-max-widths, xl) == map-get($grid-breakpoints, xl)
```

...but this is only true for the `xl` values.

I would think that the values of those 3 things (`$container-max-widths`, `$grid-breakpoints` & ,`$grid-gutter-width-base`) would have to be inherently related somehow, but other than at the `xl` level, they all seem completely arbitrary.

Is there some sort of relationship between these (or other values) that I'm missing? Is the mathematical relationship at the `xl` level just a coincidence?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19438900/3258604

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19438900/3258604) that [makshh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3258604/makshh) directed me to in their comment, the default values assigned to the `$container-max-width` and `$grid-breakpoint` maps are not directly related in anyway, beyond controlling what container max-widths are at particular breakpoints.